# Integration over a set

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0<x<y<2x<2\}$

Now I've got to integrate$\int_{\Omega}{ydxdy}$ over $\Omega$.
Something is wrong with my integral because I get the false result.
I've calculated $\int_{0}^{2}[\int_{x}^{2x}{y}dy]dx$ with result 4. Have I chosen a wrong integral?

Comment: $2x<2\implies x<1$

Answer (score 0):

You should be integrating $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$. So this is like a triangle with vertices $(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)$.

You will have $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_y^1 y \,dx \,dy = \frac{1}{6}$

Also notice that the corresponding solid is an oblique pyramid with a right-isosceles base of $1$, height $1$. The volume is thus $\frac{1}{2}*(1)^2*\frac{1}{3}=\boxed{\frac{1}{6}}$

Answer (score 0):

The right integral is:
$$
\int_0^1\int_x^{2x}y\,dy.
$$
Note that $x\in (0,1)$, while $y\in (0,2)$.